# wc -L reports a line-length of 8 for a tab-char. bug or feature?

Tags: text-processing

`-L` is a useful feature of `wc`, or so I thought. It prints the length of the longest line. For some reason it expands a single-byte tab-char to a length of 8.
Is there some way to set this to not "expand" the tab? and what might be the rationale behind this expansion?

```
echo -n $'\t' | wc -L
```

outputs  `8`

wc (GNU coreutils) 7.4
GNU bash, version 4.1.5

Comment: The -n is orthogonal to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find no bug report related to this, and the following lines in the [source file `wc.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/wc.c?id=e361bff8a5ef97fd784a79ce789d8ac6c7e20fc7#n454)

```
    case '\t':
        linepos += 8 - (linepos % 8);
```

seem to deliberately choose to behave in this way, probably to give an hint for width needed to display the file on screen.

A quick alternative could be

```
echo -n $'\t' | tr '\t' ' ' | wc -L
```

Comment: Thanks enzo, I've now found that although `man wc` makes no mention of this issue, it is stated in `info coreutils 'wc invocation'` (which 'man' refers too)... Also, after trawling the google-sphere a bit more, I found this as an alternative `echo -n $'\t' | expand -t1 | wc -L`, which is pretty much the same as your alternative, but I've thrown it in for good measure..  And although the following link is a *recompile wc hack**, it may be of interest to some: [wc support for different tab widths](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-06/msg00026.html)

Comment: Counting tabs as 8 characters was [added to GNU Coreutils in 1997](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/wc.c?id=ab5ff1597f5d734b711fbd95389cefcc8203d51c) in the original patch that implemented the `-L`/`--max-line-length` feature. Before that they were counted as 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

The wc -L description was ambiguous. It returns the widest display width. To control tab expansion you can filter through `expand` first.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a tab is expanded to the next position, (divisible by 8)+1 `[1, 9, 17, 25, ...]`, so if you ask for it, you get it.

Note, that the -n is irrelevant for the question, but the $ is not.

```
echo foo$'\t' | wc -L
```

will return 8 too, because

```
echo foo$'\t'bar 
foo     bar
```

You can omit the $, if you use -e for echo:

```
echo -e '\t' | wc -L
8
```

So if you want to count the '\t' as a single byte, just omit -e and $:

```
echo '\t' | wc -L
2
```

Comment: Yes, expanding tabs is common enough for a printed/displayed output, but I found it odd that a program which *counts* bytes and words would count **1** character as anything other than **1** character... btw `echo '\t'` does not output a tab-char (\x09). It outputs a line whose length is 2, ie. a `'\'` and a `'t'`. A newline is not parte of a line's length... (I had a `-n` in my example to check whether `wc` would properly process a file which has no trailing newline-char...)

Comment: `wc --help` says: `-L, --max-line-length  print the length of the longest line?`. It doesn't talk about bytes, but line lengths.

Comment: Yes, it does say *"print the length of the longest line"*...`  but it **does not say** *"We assume that you want tabs expanded (not the usual character count, like most other length functions).. Oh, by the way, we will expand tabs to 8 spaces, regardless of what your specific tab stops are set to."*  ... That is the trap.. It is not properly documented.

Comment: How do you set the tab with? In Bash? Furthermore: Tabs are not expanded to 8 spaces, but to positions, see `echo -e foo'\t'bar | wc -L` which results in 11, not in 14.

Comment: In the above `foo\tbar` example, `wc` has *assumed* tab-stops at a nominal spacing of *8*... The following example shows how `wc` ignores the currently active tab-stop settings.  It outputs a line to the terminal which is 8 terminal-columns wide/long, yet `wc` reports it to be 11. This example sets tab-stops to every 6th column... `tabs -6; echo 12345678;  echo -e "foo\tbar"|tee >(wc -L)`

Comment: It think it's a gross error from the devs to assume _anyone_ using this switch will know upfront about \t adding +8 to line length. How hard is to add an extra sentence in the manual clarifying?

Comment: @fered: So I conclude, that wc does not assume, that the size of the text should be measured in lengths, defined by the current terminal session.

Comment: @Juaco: If you think it is important, you should try it.

Comment: @user unknown: it's the maintainer's responsibility to not leave undocumented such a detail. Not user's.

Comment: Well - maybe the developer is not reading your wishes here, but maybe he would response to an email? Talking to me is rather senseless. Do you want to complain, or do you want to change the situation?

Comment: @userunknown: I certainly don't want to change the situation. Do YOU want it? You send an email. I do want to just express what I have in my mind, "complain" is a different thing.