# How to print the longest line in a file?

Tags: bash, awk, filter

I'm looking for the simplest method to print the longest line in a file. I did some googling and surprisingly couldn't seem to find an answer. I frequently print the length of the longest line in a file, but I don't know how to actually print the longest line. Can anyone provide a solution to print the longest line in a file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about when there are multiple "longest" lines?. Because you want more than a simple maximum length, do you want to see all instances of lines which are equal longest?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655372/longest-line-in-a-file

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
cat ./text | awk ' { if ( length > x ) { x = length; y = $0 } }END{ print y }'
```

**UPD**: summarizing all the advices in the comments

```
awk 'length > max_length { max_length = length; longest_line = $0 } END { print longest_line }' ./text
```

Comment: It is, both calling another command (`cat`), and using a pipe are expensive operations, not to mention that it's more efficient for awk to just read the file. The performance implications are definitely noticeable if this is done frequently, and even so, you are completely misusing `cat`.

Comment: @laebshade There absolutely is a reason -- it's so you don't need to remember which commands take filenames and which don't, or care about which command is going to execute first in the pipeline. If you're going to be writing a script that gets run frequently, by all means worry about something like this. If you're writing a one-off thing to find the longest line in a file, the extra process and fractional amount of time consumed is completely irrelevant. It's silly that people are so obsessed with it here, it's incredibly minor

Comment: @Keith Thompson: `cat` is not useless here. It might be useless to a computer but for a human reader it could provide value. The first variant clearly shows the input. The flow is more natural (from left to right). In the second case you don't know what the input is unless you scroll the window.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Even if you want it at the left, you don't need `cat`. `< file command` works just fine.

Comment: @Chris Down: It doesn't print the file if you omit command. It is inconvenient if you build command interactively.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The fact that a redirection can be written at the beginning of a command is somewhat obscure; `< filename command` is equivalent to `filename < command` in every shell I've tried.  But once you're aware of it, you can take advantage of it when writing long pipes that clearly show the direction of the data flow (without invoking an extra command): `< input-file command1 | command2 | command3 > output-file`

Comment: @KeithThompson, ITYM *...equivalent to `command < filename`...*. The only shell I know where `<file cmd` doesn't work is `fish`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right, of course. `< filename command` is equivalent to `command < filename`. For that matter, `command arg1 <filename arg2` is equivalent to `command arg1 arg2 <filename`. (In most shells) -- but it's hard to think of a good reason to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 18):

```
cat filename | awk '{ print length }' | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: +1 There were lots of interesting solutions to this but this was the simplest. (It would be simpler without the cat by letting awk read the file but why quibble?)

Comment: This I can rememeber.  ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ answer is probably most efficent though

Comment: Nit: This only prints the length and not the line itself

Comment: As I just learned from Volker Siegel's answer, this whole expensive command can be replaced by a simple `wc -L filename`.
And @ChrisWue is correct - but I stumbled upon this whole question trying to find the LENGTH of the longest line, and this answered it :-)

Comment: To also print the line, change the stuff after `cat filename` to `| awk '{ print length " " $0 }' | sort -n | tail -1`

Answer (score 13):

### Grep the first longest line

```
grep -Em1 "^.{$(wc -L <file.txt)}\$" file.txt
```

The command is unusually hard to read without practise because it mixes shell- and regexp syntax.
For explanation, I will use simplified pseudocode first. The lines starting with `##` do not run in the shell.
This simplified code uses the file name F, and leaves out quoting and parts of regexps for readability.

### How it works

The command has two parts, a `grep`- and a `wc` invocation:

`## grep "^.{$( wc -L F )}$" F`

The `wc` is used in a process expansion, `$( ... )`, so it is run before `grep`. It calculates the length of the longest line. The shell expansion syntax is mixed with the regular expression pattern syntax in a confusing way, so I will decompose the process expansion:

`## wc -L F`
   `42`
   `## grep "^.{42}$" F`

Here, the process expansion was replaced with the value it would return, creating the `grep` commandline that is used. We can now read the regular expression more easily: It matches exactly from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the line. The expression between them matches any character except newline, repeated by 42 times. Combined, that is lines that consist of exactly 42 characters.

Now, back to real shell commands: The `grep` option `-E` (`--extended-regexp`) allows to not escape the `{}` for readability. Option `-m 1` (`--max-count=1`) makes it stop after the first line is found. The `<` in the `wc` command writes the file to its stdin, to prevent `wc` from printing the file name together with the length.

### Which longest lines?

To make the examples more readable with the filename occurring twice, I will use a variable `f` for the filename; Each `$f` in the example could be replaced by the file name.

```
f="file.txt"
```

Show the **first longest line** - the first line that is as long as the longest line:

```
grep -E -m1 "^.{$(wc -L <"$f")}\$" "$f"
```

Show **all longest lines** - all lines that are as long as the longest line:

```
grep -E "^.{$(wc -L <"$f")}\$" "$f"
```

Show the **last longest line** - the last line that is as long as the longest line:

```
tac "$f" | grep -E -m1 "^.{$(wc -L <"$f")}\$"
```

Show the **single longest line** - the longest line longer than all other lines, or fail:

```
[ $(grep -E "^.{$(wc -L <"$f")}\$" "$f" | wc -l) = 1 ] && grep -E "^.{$(wc -L <"$f")}\$" "$f"
```

(The last command is even more inefficient than the others, as it repeats the complete grep command. It should obviously be decomposed so that the output of `wc` and the lines written by `grep` are saved to variables.
Note that all longest lines may actually be all lines. For saving in a variable, only the first two lines need to be kept.)

Comment: Wow great answer, learned a lot from it. thanks

Comment: Interesting approach but doesn't work for long lines (`grep: regular expression too big`) (I have some files with lines with lengths of around 760kb)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){
           $l=length;  
           $l>$m && do {$c=$_; $m=$l}  
         } print $c' file.txt
```

Or, if you want to print *all* the longest lines

```
perl -e 'while(<>){
           $l=length;
           push @{$k{$l}},$_;
           $m=$l if $l>$m;
         } print @{$k{$m}}' file.txt
```

---

Since I had nothing better to do, I ran some benchmarks on a 625M text file. Surprisingly, my Perl solution was consistently faster than the others. Granted, the difference with the accepted `awk` solution is tiny, but it is there. Obviously, solutions that print multiple lines are slower so I have sorted by type, fastest to slowest.

Print only one of the longest lines:

```
$ time perl -e 'while(<>){
           $l=length;  
           $l>$m && do {$c=$_; $m=$l}  
         } print $c' file.txt 
real    0m3.837s
user    0m3.724s
sys     0m0.096s



$ time awk 'length > max_length { max_length = length; longest_line = $0 }
 END { print longest_line }' file.txt
real    0m5.835s
user    0m5.604s
sys     0m0.204s



$ time sed -rn "/.{$(<file.txt expand -t1 |wc -L)}/{p;q}" file.txt 
real    2m37.348s
user    2m39.990s
sys     0m1.868s
```

Print all longest lines :

```
$ time perl -e 'while(<>){
           $l=length;
           push @{$k{$l}},$_;
           $m=$l if $l>$m;
         } print @{$k{$m}}' file.txt 
real    0m9.263s
user    0m8.417s
sys     0m0.760s


$ time awk 'length >x { delete y; x=length }
     length==x { y[NR]=$0 } END{ for (z in y) print y[z] }' file.txt
real    0m10.220s
user    0m9.925s
sys     0m0.252s


## This is Chris Down's bash solution
$ time ./a.sh < file.txt 
Max line length: 254
Lines matched with that length: 2
real    8m36.975s
user    8m17.495s
sys     0m17.153s
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -rn "/.{$(<file expand -t1 |wc -L)}/{p;q}" file
```

This first reads the file inside the command substitution and outputs the length of the longest line, (previously, `expand` converts tabs to spaces, to overcome the semantics of `wc -L` -- each tab in the line will add *8 instead of 1* to line length). This length is then used in a `sed` expression meaning "find a line this number of characters long, print it, then quit". So this actually can be as optimal as the longest line is near to the top of the file, heheh (thanks fered for the awesome and constructive comments).

Another, I had thought earlier than the sed one (in bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    (( ${#line} > max )) && max=${#line} && longest="$line"
done
echo "$longest"
```

Comment: This method is very expensive and slow.

Comment: @Chris Down: Oh yes it is. But the question was about the sortest method, not the most efficient. WOrks finely for small to medium files or non critical tasks, though.

Comment: *WARNING*: 
  wc's option `-L, --max-line-length` prints the length of the longest line, according to the man page, but if you dig deeper (as in when you get **wrong / unexpected** results), you find that this option increments the length by **8** for each **1** tab char `\x09`  
  see this [Unix & Linux Q/A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20551/wc-l-reports-a-line-length-of-8-for-a-tab-char-bug-or-feature)

Comment: PS. Your answer will print all the "equally longest" lines, which is probably a *good* thing... To force *wc* to count only 1 char per tab, this works. `sed -rn "/.{$(<file expand -t1 |wc -L)}/p" file`

Comment: @fered: whops! _that_ (about wc -L) is new, and could definitely alter results when the input has tabs. Thx! Regards both 1st and PS: I'll complement with a bash based one I devised before this, but i think it'll output the _first_ longest line only (would be trivial to modify it to output all longest lines, just push them to an array!)

Comment: `read line` will interpret backslash-escaped chars as the literal char, eg `\A` resloves to `A`, which of course effectively reports a shorter than actual byte-usage... To prevent this *escaped* interpretation, use: `read -r line` . . . . Also, to make the *sed+wc* version quit after the first "longest line", change `p` to `{p;q}` .. `sed -rn "/.{$(<file expand -t1 |wc -L)}/{p;q}" file`

Comment: fered: "awesome" falls short. Updating...

Comment: This is the best method using only Bash feature. awk and sed will both read line by line to determine what is the longest line.

Answer (score 2):

The following example was going to be, and should have been, a comment to *dmitry.malikov's* answer, but because of the *Useless Use of Visible Comment Space*  there, I've chosen to present it here, where it will at least be seen...

This is a simple variation of the *dmitry's* 
single-pass awk method.
It prints all "equal longest" lines.  (Note. `delete array` is a gawk extension).

```
awk 'length >x { delete y; x=length }
     length==x { y[NR]=$0 } END{ for (z in y) print y[z] }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

_max_length=0
while IFS= read -r _line; do
    _length="${#_line}"
    if (( _length > _max_length )); then
        _max_length=${_length}
        _max_line=( "${_line}" )
    elif (( _length == _max_length )); then
        _max_line+=( "${_line}" )
    fi
done

printf 'Max line length: %d\n' "${_max_length}"
printf 'Lines matched with that length: %d\n' "${#_max_line[@]}"
(( ${#_max_line[@]} )) && printf '%s\n' '----------------' "${_max_line[@]}"
```

Comment: As-is, the code can return invalid results. Setting `_max_line[0]=${_line}` does not remove the rest of any previously accumulated shorter "longest lines"... `unset _max_line` will clear the entire array...

Comment: @fered Thanks for that, was written pretty quickly. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -n" }' file.txt | tail -1
```

Reference: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-sort-lines-by-length-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a small shell script for this. It displays length, line # and line itself by length that exceeds a particular size like 80 characters:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Author: Surinder

if test $# -lt 2
then
   echo "usage: $0 length file1 file2 ..."
   echo "usage: $0 80 hello.c"
   exit 1
fi

length=$1

shift

LONGLINE=/tmp/longest-line-$$.awk

cat << EOF > $LONGLINE
  BEGIN {
  }

  /.*/ {
    current_length=length(\$0);
    if (current_length >= expected_length) {
       printf("%d at line # %d %s\n", current_length, NR, \$0);
    }
  }

  END {
  }
EOF

for file in $*
do
  echo "$file"
  cat $file | awk -v expected_length=$length -f $LONGLINE |sort -nr
done

rm $LONGLINE
```

https://github.com/lordofrain/tools/blob/master/longest-line/longest-line.sh

Comment: There are a few improvements you could make. [Quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222). This will break on any file names that contain whitespace or other strange characters. Using `$*` is rarely a good idea, [you want `"$@"`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/22222). The `/.*/` in your `awk` doesn't do anything since that matches empty lines as well. You could avoid escaping the `\$0` if you single quote the `'EOF'`. Why use an empty `BEGIN{}` block? Finally, you don't need `cat`, just `awk . . . "$file" | . . . `

Comment: You couuld also just do the whole thing in awk directly: `awk -vmax=15 '{len=length($0); if(len>=max){printf("%s, %d at line # %d %s\n", FILENAME, len, NR, $0);}}' file*`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using python

```
python -c 'import sys;print(max(open(sys.argv[1],"r").readlines(), key=len))' file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

(edit of code above in [@ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ (Dmitry Malikov)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3737/%d0%94%d0%9c%d0%98%d0%a2%d0%a0%d0%98%d0%99-%d0%9c%d0%90%d0%9b%d0%98%d0%9a%d0%9e%d0%92)'s
popular post from 2011-11-13:)

this prints out the line number, the length, and underlines the contents of only the first longest line:

`awk 'length>len{len=length;line=FNR;long=$0}END{print"line="line" len="len" long=\033[4m\n"long"\033[0m"}'` **`<"${filename}"`**

(underlining seemed best because the text might contain color sequences or white space.)

also, to strip out non-printing characters (if desired),  instead of just **`<"${filename}"`**,
you could use this very concise "ansifilter" alternative found
[here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12043/remove-color-special-escape-ansi-codes-from-text-with-sed):

**`<(sed "s,\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" "${filename}"|expand)`**

(or check out [the *real* ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) for **serious** projects--thanks to whoever mentioned it before me!)

Comment: Hi @AnonyMuse00yahoo, I declined your flag because I don't understand what you mean. If you want to propose an edit to Dmitry Malikov's answer, go ahead! If you want to post a new answer yourself, you can also do this. This answer is deleted (it can't be any more deleted than this). You can still see it because it's yours, but other users won't  (unless they have  enough reputation points to see deleted posts).

Comment: I also undeleted this answer, at least temporarily, so that you can respond to my comment. Just include `@terdon` and I will be notified and we can sort this out.

Comment: @terdon  thanks!  but it seems that even with this answer deleted, i cannot re-answer the question anew.  is it only possible to ever have one answer per user per question?  i guess i am trying to start over on this question with a blank slate, now that i actually understand how edits and revisions work.  i am kind of a perfectionist.  i also understand the original question better and have better ideas.

Comment: I don't know of any reason you wouldn't be able to post. The system does give you a popup asking if you are sure, could you be stopping at that? If not, you can simply click on the "add another answer" or, if this is deleted "post your answer" and you should be fine. What do you actually see?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `wc`:

```
wc -L fileName
```

Comment: Please read the question again. The required output is the longest line itself, not the length of the longest line. Also see [Peter.O's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24509/how-to-print-the-longest-line-in-a-file/74291#comment32873_24511) regarding `wc -L`'s drawback.

Comment: For the xy problem that I had, this was helpful. It does not answer the question in the OP, but it is relevant tangential information and I'm happy that it was here.