# bash script explanation

Tags: linux, bash, mktemp

I have below script which I am unable to understand. Can someone explain the same.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
skip=14
tmpdir=`/bin/mktemp -d ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/gzexe.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1

prog="${tmpdir}/`echo \"$0\" | sed 's|^.*/||'`"

if /usr/bin/tail -n +$skip "$0" | "/bin"/gzip -cd > "$prog"; then
  /bin/chmod 700 "$prog"
  trap '/bin/rm -rf $tmpdir; exit $res' EXIT
  "$prog" ${1+"$@"}; res=$?
else
  echo "Cannot decompress $0"
  /bin/rm -rf $tmpdir
  exit 1
fi;
exit $res
```

Comment: looks like a self-extracting shell script (a [shar archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) or similar) to me (assuming you've only posted the first 14 lines of the file).  All but the first 14 lines ($skip) are piped into  `gzip -cd` for uncompression and then redirected to a file.   Really, though,  you should ask more specific questions about whichever parts of the script you don't understand.   Asking "what does this script do?" is far too big a question, in general.

Comment: Yes it is self extracting script. This is the complete script and not a part of it. The script is called from another script without passing any parameters .The script is creating temp dir, and extracting what inside?  I need to know what will be the value of prog variable and  the script is executing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like cas and kcmakwana say, this script is self extracting.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This is a shebang to signifiy this is a unix shell script.

```
skip=14
```

We declare a variable `$skip` with a value of the string `14`

```
tmpdir=`/bin/mktemp -d ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/gzexe.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
```

Here the grave accents signifiy to execute the contents and drop that in the new command string. (Is this different from `$(my command)`)? Here we are trying to declare a name for a temporary directory. The `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` code means we take the value of `$TMPDIR` environmental variable, if it exists, else we use `/tmp` and then append the string `/gzexe.XXXXXXXXXX` to the path we are generating. The `|| exit 1` means if that command fails we exit this script with an error of level 1 (0 would be successful). See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892604/what-is-the-meaning-of-exit-0-exit-1-and-exit-2-in-a-bash-script) for more on exit codes.

```
prog="${tmpdir}/`echo \"$0\" | sed 's|^.*/||'`"
```

Here we are defining another variable for a file path. The `$0` is expanding the name of this script. The `sed` command we pipe that string into is trimming the leading `./` part of that path. Think of sed here as a search and replace function for strings you pipe into it. So if we named this script `myscript.sh`, `$0` is `./myscript.sh` and `$prog` should contain `/tmp/myscript.sh`. Is this best behavior?

```
if /usr/bin/tail -n +$skip "$0" | "/bin"/gzip -cd > "$prog"; then
```

Here we pipe out the contents starting at line 14 this script, `$0` and pipe that contents into gzip with the `-c and -d` flags which in turn decompresses the incoming text and prints the results to standard out. Next that standard output is redirected into the `$prog` file path we declared before. Is this the best behavior? Would it be more safe to explicitly echo the intended contents into `$prog`?

```
  /bin/chmod 700 "$prog"
```

Here we set the permissions for the file we generated such that the owner can read/write/execute but others  cannot do anything with the file.

```
  trap '/bin/rm -rf $tmpdir; exit $res' EXIT
```

A typical scenario for using the trap command is catching the SIGINT signal. This signal is sent by the system when the user interrupts the execution of the script by pressing Ctrl+C. So when the user sends a ctrl-c command, the script will try to delete the file at `$tmpdir` and exit with level `$res` we declare in the next line

```
  "$prog" ${1+"$@"}; res=$?
exit $res
```

Here we execute the script at `$prog` and pass to it arguments of `${1+"$@"}` which basically means we expand whatever arguments were passed into this script, i.e. `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`. See an explanation for that synatax [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68484/what-does-1-mean-in-a-shell-script-and-how-does-it-differ-from). Finally we save the exit status result from that command and save it into `$res` (`$?` is the most recent foreground pipeline exit status). Finally we exit with the same exit level.

```
else
  echo "Cannot decompress $0"
  /bin/rm -rf $tmpdir
  exit 1
fi;
```

Pretty straightforward, if the `if` command above didn't work out, we delete the temporary script copy at `$tmpdir` and exit with status 1 (error).