# Bash: slice of positional parameters

Tags: bash, parameter, array

How can I get a slice of `$@` in Bash without first having to copy all positional parameters to another array like this?

```
argv=( "$@" )
echo "${argv[@]:2}";
```

Comment: Always quote `"$@"`. You `argv` assignment would break if any args contained spaces.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the same format as for any other array. To extract the 2nd and 3rd elements from `$@`, you would do:

```
echo "${@:1:2}"
          - -
          | |----> slice length
          |------> slice starting index
```

Comment: But this seems to work on a char by char basis in v4.1.2, is there a way to do it on a word by word basis?

Comment: @AlexejMagura I don't understand what you mean. That acts on the elements of the array. If you have one-character elements, it will work "on characters". If each element is a word, it works on words. Are you maybe trying this on a string and not an array?

Comment: I'm trying it on a copy of "$@", which I guess might become a string at that point, I'm not sure.

Comment: On bash 4.2.46, `"${@:1:2}"` actually gives me the **1st** and **2nd** **command line arguments**. Meanwhile, `"${@:1}"` gives me the **full command line arguments**, and `"${@:0}"` gives me the **script name followed by full command line arguments**.

Comment: @Rockallite well, yes. The 2nd and 3rd elements of the `$@`  array are the 1st and 2nd arguments. `"${@:1}"` will print the entire array starting with the 2nd element (the 1st argument) and `${@:0}` the entire array starting from the 1st element which is the name of the script. What were you expecting?

Comment: @terdon However, when I copy it directly like this `argv=("$@")`, there are only command line arguments, no script name. So `"${argv[@]:1:2}` will be the actual **2nd and 3rd command line arguments**, while `${@:1:2}` is the **1st and 2nd command line arguments**.

Comment: ...and you mentioned `"${@:1:2}"` for ***2nd and 3rd elements from `$@`***. Nothing wrong. Just a bit confusing for me. And I want to clarify it.

Comment: @Rockallite yeah, it is confusing, I know. And I just realized I don't understand it as well as I thought I did, myself. The first thing to remember is that arrays in bash (as in most programming languages) start at `0` and not at `1`. So the element at *index* `1` is actually the *second* and not the first. Now, when you print `"$@"`, you are [printing a *string*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/22222), not an array, and apparently bash will remove the script name automatically. Basically, `$@` is special and doesn't behave like other arrays. This probably merits its own question.

Comment: If you are working with an array A and not the argument list, the syntax is `echo "${A[@]:1:2}"` to get two elements starting at position 1 in array A. As noted above, `echo "${A:1:2}"` will give two *characters* from the first element, starting with the character at position 1. The quotes are required if the elements of A contain spaces, if you want to preserve element structure.

Comment: It appears `echo "${@:2}"` gives the 2nd command-line argument, and onwards, to the very end. Can you add this as an example, and an explanation of it, to your answer too?

Comment: Great answer by the way; [I expounded upon it in my own answer here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664956/114401)

Answer (score 11):

### More array slicing examples in bash

In place of using `some_array_variable` in your code (`argv` in your case), simply use `@` in that variable name's place. The symbol `@` represents the *input argument array*, and you can treat it exactly like you'd treat any other array. The confusion is simply that we are accustomed to seeing it almost always paired with the `$` character like this: `$@`, and so we don't realize that the `@` character is the array itself, and can be used alone as an array variable as well.

**So, here are some examples:**

Slice from the input argument array, `@`, which is normally seen and accessed simply as `$@`:

```bsh
# array slicing basic format 1: grab a certain length starting at a certain
# index
echo "${@:2:5}"
#         │ │
#         │ └────> slice length
#         └──────> slice starting index 

# array slicing basic format 2: grab all remaining array elements starting at a
# certain index through to the end
echo "${@:2}"
#         │
#         │
#         └──────> slice starting index
```

### More array reminders to myself:

The following are general array reminders to myself that may benefit others landing on this page too.

```bsh
# store a slice from an array into a new array
new_array=("${@:4}")

# print the entire array
echo "new_array = ${new_array[@]}"
```

**Here is a runnable example of generic array slicing and array element access in bash**, inspired by [this source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217877/single-parenthesis-in-bash-variable-assignment/217878#217878):

*(Use `@` as the input argument array if desired, instead of `a` below, according to your use case)*

```bsh
a=(one two three four five six)   # define a new array, `a`, with 6 elements
echo "$a"           # print first element of array a
echo "${a}"         # print first element of array a
echo "${a[0]}"      # print first element of array a
echo "${a[1]}"      # print *second* element of array a
echo "${#a[@]}"     # print number of elements in array a
echo "${a[@]:1:3}"  # print 2nd through 4th elements; ie: the 3 elements
                    # starting at index 1, inclusive, so: indices 1, 2, and 3
                    # (output: `two three four`)
echo "${a[@]:1}"    # print 2nd element onward
```

### Run it all

Copy and paste all code chunks above into a file called `array_slicing_demo.sh`, and mark it executable with `chmod +x array_slicing_demo.sh` so that you can run it. Or, just download my demo [array_slicing_demo.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/array_slicing_demo.sh) file from my [eRCaGuy_hello_worl](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world)d repo here.

Then, run it like this:

```bsh
./array_slicing_demo.sh a b c d e f g h i j k
```

...and you will see the following output:

> ```
> b c d e f
> b c d e f g h i j k
> new_array = d e f g h i j k
> one
> one
> one
> two
> 6
> two three four
> two three four five six
> ```

### References

1. [Bash: slice of positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82060/bash-slice-of-positional-parameters/82061#82061)
2. [Single parenthesis in bash variable assignment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217877/single-parenthesis-in-bash-variable-assignment/217878#217878)

<sub>Keywords: array access in bash; bash array indexing; access elments in arrays in bash; bash array slicing; print arrays in bash; print array elements in bash</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this:

```
somefunc() {
    local message="$1"
    shift
    echo "message = $message"
    echo "other   = $@"
}
somefunc first second third goforth
```

which will print:

```
message = first
other   = second third goforth
```

You can expand on the concept by `shift`ing after second, third, etc. argument

Answer (score 1):

For function parameters, the answer with `echo "${@:1:2}"` didn't work for me at all. Also, I wanted the slice-off the first element, since it was a different parameter. What did work was:

```
function foo(){ #takes single param + array of params
  local param1="$1".                   #first param
  local -a tmp=( "${@}" )              #copy all params
  local -a rem_params=( "${tmp[@]:1}") #slice off first:Works!
# local -a rem_params=( "${@[@]:1}"  ) #DID NOT WORK, ERROR
# local -a rem_params=( "{@:1}"      ) #DID NOT SLICE
  echo "${rem_params[@]}"
}
```

Maybe I'll write to test to see how this works with positional arguments for at the script-level, but no time right now.