# Single parenthesis in bash variable assignment

Tags: bash, array

I was wondering about single parentheses in bash. I know that they are used for executing commands in subshells and that they are used for creating arrays, but are they used for anything else?

One thing that caught my attention is that when you use the in variable assignment, like

```
var=(hello)
echo $var    # hello
```

bash doesn't generate an error or anything, and the output is the same as if

```
var=hello
```

Are these two variable definitions the same or is there a difference?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your case parenthesis `()` are used as array definition, for example

```
a=(one two three)   # array definition
echo "${a}"         # print first element of array a
echo "${a[0]}"      # print first element of array a
echo "${a[1]}"      # print *second* element of array a
echo "${#a[@]}"     # print number of elements in array a
```

If you put single variable in array then you just have an array with single element.

---

To answer your other question whether parenthesis are also used for anything else: there are many situations in `bash` that in combination with other characters they can be used as:

- command substitution: `$()`
- process substitution: `<()` and `>()`
- subshell: `(command)`
- arithmetic evaluation: `(())`
- function definition: `fun () { echo x; }`
- pattern list in glob: `?()`, `*()`, `+()`, `@()`, `!()` (*only if `extglob` is enable*)

Comment: Right, I actually didn't think of that. But so `var=(1 2 3); echo $var` is the same as `var=(1 2 3); echo ${var[0]}`?

Comment: Yes, the result in `bash` is the same.

Comment: Do we need `""` in `echo "${a}"`?

Comment: @nn0p Yes we do, if we don't want to perform split and glob operation on `a`. Consider for example `a=*`, then try `echo $a` and `echo "$a"`.

Comment: I expounded upon your answer to make your array example more complete, by adding some bash array slicing examples to it in the bottom of my answer here: [Bash: slice of positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664956/114401).