# What is the difference between [@] and [*] when referencing bash array values?

Tags: bash, array

[This Bash guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_10_02) says:

> If the index number is `@` or `*`, all members of an array are referenced.

When I do this:

```bsh
LIST=(1 2 3)
for i in "${LIST[@]}"; do
  echo "example.$i"
done
```

it gives the desired result:

```
example.1
example.2
example.3
```

But when I use `${LIST[*]}`, I get

```
example.1 2 3
```

instead.

Why?

Edit: when using `printf`, `@` and `*` actually do give the same results.

Comment: It seems to work for me. I tried both @ and * and it seems to produce the same result both the times. What shell you are using? Run `echo $SHELL` and paste the output to your question.

Comment: My example was wrong, this actually happens only with `echo`, not with `printf`, I just noticed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Comment: @goldilocks The other question is about `$*` and `$@`. Though, the answer would be similar and one question _could_ be considered a subset of the other, they are different questions.

Comment: printf and echo give the same result (tested on GNU bash, version 5.0.17), i.e., the difference between @ and * has nothing to do with the difference between printf and echo.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The difference is subtle; `"${LIST[*]}"` (like `"$*"`) creates one argument, while `"${LIST[@]}"` (like `"$@"`) will expand each item into separate arguments, so:

```bsh
LIST=(1 2 3)
for i in "${LIST[@]}"; do
    echo "example.$i"
done
```

will deal with the list (print it) as multiple variables.

But:

```bsh
LIST=(1 2 3)
for i in "${LIST[*]}"; do
    echo "example.$i"
done
```

will deal with the list as one variable.

Comment: Do you know where the difference between `echo` and `printf` comes from? Because with `printf` in the for loop, the * list reference is treated as multiple variables.

Comment: What does it mean for something to be dealt with as one versus multiple variables? I wonder if you could provide a practical example to illustrate the difference.

Comment: Wow, it's worth while mentioning that when you do the one with the star that it separates the values by the value of "IFS". For example, try this: IFS="/" && LIST=(1 2 3); for i in "${LIST[*]}"; do echo "$i"; done; and you should get "1/2/3". Hell, if you couldn't remember any other method you could use this replace a character now that I think about it by setting IFS to the before character, splitting it using read -a <<< '$string", and then changing the IFS to the replacement before looping through and reconstructing it. Rather brute force but still...

Comment: Hey, check it out! https://i.imgur.com/WYYtdvQ.png. It totally worked. Script is: IFS=" " && read -a arrBefore; IFS="/" && for i in "${arrBefore[*]}"; do echo "$i"; done;

Comment: Yes and **note** that it is the surrounding **double quotes** that in turn preserves the `"${LIST[*]}"` as `"1 2 3"` and prevents it from getting split one more time into `"1" "2" "3"`. _Always_ double quote variable expansions UNLESS YOU WANT a spaces in their expanded value to cause splitting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348659/19166437

Answer (score 10):

Using `[*]` will create **a single string**, with each element of your array joined with the first character of `$IFS` (a space by default) in between elements¹.

Using `[@]` will create **a list**.

Examples:

Creating an array:

```
$ list=( a b "big fish" c d )
```

Printing each element individually:

```
$ printf 'data: ---%s---\n' "${list[@]}"
data: ---a---
data: ---b---
data: ---big fish---
data: ---c---
data: ---d---
```

Creating a single string and printing that:

```
$ printf 'data: ---%s---\n' "${list[*]}"
data: ---a b big fish c d---
```

Again, but with a custom delimiter:

```
$ IFS='/'
$ printf 'data: ---%s---\n' "${list[*]}"
data: ---a/b/big fish/c/d---
```

Note that using these expansions *without* double quotes rarely makes sense.

---

<sup>¹ or nothing if `$IFS` is set but empty (after `IFS=`) or a space if `$IFS` is unset (after `unset -v IFS`) with some variations between shells if the first character of `$IFS` is a multibyte character, or something that cannot be decoded as a character.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Consider the simple case that list elements do not contain special characters (e.g. blanks). Then the quotes can be dropped. Then @ and * will give the same result.

```
LIST=(1 2 3)
for i in ${LIST[*]}; do
  echo "example.$i"
done
```

ouput:

```
example.1
example.2
example.3
```

Now consider the case that elements contain blanks:

```
LIST=(1 "a b" 3)
for i in ${LIST[*]}; do
  echo "example.$i"
done
```

In this case, @ and * still give the same result:

```
example.1
example.a
example.b
example.3
```

But it is not what we desire since "a b" is split as two elements rather than one elmement. So we need to use quotes to prevent this:

```
LIST=(1 "a b" 3)
for i in "${LIST[*]}"; do
  echo "example.$i"
done
```

But the result is `example.1 a b 3`. Next we change * to @:

```
LIST=(1 "a b" 3)
for i in "${LIST[@]}"; do
  echo "example.$i"
done
```

We finally get the desired result:

```
example.1
example.a b
example.3
```

Summarizing the above result, we see that @ allows element-wisely operation when being operated by some operators, e.g. quote marks.

Comment: "the simple case that list elements do not contain blanks" that is not sufficient for dropping quotes safely.

Comment: edited to " do not contain special characters (e.g., blanks)".