# Bash's read builtin errors on a string-based timeout option specification but not an array-based one. Why?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, shell-builtin, bash-array

In reading through the source to [fff](https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff/blob/5b90a8599cce3333672947438bb1718e1298e068/fff) to learn more about Bash programming, I saw a timeout option passed to `read` as an array [here](https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff/blob/5b90a8599cce3333672947438bb1718e1298e068/fff#L1138):

```bsh
read "${read_flags[@]}" -srn 1 && key "$REPLY"
```

The value of `read_flags` is set [like this](https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff/blob/5b90a8599cce3333672947438bb1718e1298e068/fff#L1107):

```bsh
read_flags=(-t 0.05)
```

(The resulting `read` invocation intended is therefore `read -t 0.05 -srn 1`).

I can't quite figure out why a string could not have been used, i.e.:

```bsh
read_flags="-t 0.05"
read "$read_flags" -srn 1 && key "$REPLY"
```

This string based approach results in an "invalid timeout specification".

Investigating, I came up with a test script `parmtest`:

```bsh
show() {
  for i in "$@"; do printf '[%s]' "$i"; done
  printf '\n'
}

opt_string="-t 1"
opt_array=(-t 1)

echo 'Using string-based option...'
show string "$opt_string" x y z
read "$opt_string"
echo
echo 'Using array-based option...'
show array "${opt_array[@]}" x y z
read "${opt_array[@]}"
```

Running this, with `bash parmtest` (`$BASH_VERSION` is 5.1.4(1)-release), gives:

```
Using string-based option...
[string][-t 1][x][y][z]
parmtest: line 11: read:  1: invalid timeout specification

Using array-based option...
[array][-t][1][x][y][z]
(1 second delay...)
```

I can see from the debug output that the value of `1` in the array based approach is separate and without whitespace. I can also see from the error message that there's an extra space before the `1`: `read:  1: invalid timeout specification`. My suspicions are in that area.

The strange thing is that if I use this approach with another command, e.g. `date`, the problem doesn't exist:

```bsh
show() {
  for i in "$@"; do printf '[%s]' "$i"; done
  printf '\n'
}

opt_string="-d 1"
opt_array=(-d 1)

echo 'Using string-based option...'
show string "$opt_string" x y z
date "$opt_string"
echo
echo 'Using array-based option...'
show array "${opt_array[@]}" x y z
date "${opt_array[@]}"
```

(The only differences are the `opt_string` and `opt_array` now specify `-d` not `-t` and I'm calling `date` not `read` in each case).

When run with `bash parmtest` this produces:

```
Using string-based option...
[string][-d 1][x][y][z]
Wed Sep  1 01:00:00 UTC 2021

Using array-based option...
[array][-d][1][x][y][z]
Wed Sep  1 01:00:00 UTC 2021
```

No error.

I've searched, but in vain, to find an answer to this. Moreover, the author wrote this bit [directly in one go and used an array immediately](https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff/commit/f0023f93fde103a0d69eea26b4c3f589bf68e824), which makes me wonder.

Thank you in advance.

**Update 03 Sep** : Here's the blog post where I've written up what I've learned so far from reading through `fff`, and I've referenced this question and the great answers in it too: [Exploring fff part 1 - main](https://qmacro.org/autodidactics/2021/09/03/exploring-fff-part-1-main/).

Comment: btw `for i in "$@" do printf '[%s]' "$i"` is `printf '[%s]' "$@"`. the builtin printf prints until there's no more arguments.

Comment: Brill, thanks @jthill. I'd originally had it with `echo`, but that's a weak excuse I guess :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is a difference in how the `read` builtin function and the `date` command interpret their command-line arguments.

But, first things first. In both of your examples, you place - as is recommended - quotes around the dereferencing of your shell variables, be it `"${read_flags[@]}"` in the array case or `"$read_flags"` in the scalar case.
The main reason why it is recommended to always quote your shell variables is to prevent *unwanted* word splitting. Consider the following

- You have a file called `My favorite songs.txt` with spaces in it, and want to move it to the directory `playlists/`.
- If you store the filename in a variable `$fname` and call

  ```
  mv $fname playlists/
  ```

  the `mv` command will see *four* arguments: `My`, `favorite`, `songs.txt` and `playlists/` and try to move the three nonexistant files `My`, `favorite` and `songs.txt` to the directory `playlists/`. Obviously not what you want.
- Instead, if you place the `$fname` reference in double-quotes, as in

  ```
  mv "$fname" playlists/
  ```

  it makes sure the shell passes this entire string including the spaces as *one* word to `mv`, so that it recognizes it is just one file (albeit with spaces in its name) that needs to be moved.

Now you have a situation in which you want to store *option* arguments in a shell variable. These are tricky, because sometimes they are long, sometimes short, and sometimes they take a value. There are numerous ways on how to specify options that take arguments, and usually *how they are parsed is left entirely at the discretion of the programmer* (see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/573377/377345)) for a discussion). The reason why Bash's `read` builtin and the `date` command react differently is therefore likely in the internal workings on how these two parse their command-line arguments. However, we may speculate a little.

- When storing `-t 0.05` in a scalar shell variable and passing it as `"$opt_string"`, the recipient will see this as one string containing a space (see above).
- When storing `-t` and `0.05` in an array variable and passing it as `"${opt_array[@]}"` the recipient will see this as two separate items, the `-t` and the `0.05`.<sup>(1)</sup><sup>(2)</sup>
- Many programs will use the `getopt()` function from the GNU C library for parsing command-line arguments, as is recommended by the POSIX guidelines.
- The `getopt()` distinguishes "short" options and "long" option format, e.g. `date -u` or `date --utc` in case of the `date` command. The way option *values* for an option (say, `-o` / `--option`) are interpreted by `getopt` is usually `-ovalue` or `-o value` for short options and `--option=value` or `--option value` for long options.
- When passing `-t 0.05` as *two* words to a tool that uses `getopt()`, it will take the first character after the `-` as being the option name and the next word as the option value (the `-o value` syntax). So, `read` would take `t` as option name and `0.05` as option value.
- When passing `-t 0.05` as *one* word, it will be interpreted as the `-ovalue` syntax: `getopt()` will take (again) the first character after the `-` as the option name and the remainder of the string as option value, so the value would be  `0.05` *with a leading space*.
- The `read` command apparently doesn't accept timeout specifications with a leading space. And indeed, if you call

  ```
  read -t " 0.05" -srn 1
  ```

  where the value is explicitly a string with leading space, `read` *also* complains about this.

*As a conclusion*, the `date` command is obviously written in a more lenient way when it comes to the option value for `-d` and doesn't care if the value string starts with a space. This is perhaps not unexpected, as the values that the date specifications can take on are very diverse, as opposed to the case of a timeout specification that (clearly) needs to be a number.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Note that using the `@` (as opposed to `*`) [makes a great difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/135010/377345) here, because when the array reference is quoted, all array elements will then appear as if they were individually quoted and thus could contain spaces themselves without being split further*.

<sup>(2)</sup> *In principle, there is a third option: Store `-t 0.05` in a scalar variable `$opt_string`, but pass it as `$opt_string` **without** the quotes. In this case, we would have word-splitting at the space, and again **two** items, `-t` and `0.05`, would be passed separately to the program. However, this is not the recommended way because sometimes your argument value will have explicit whitespaces that need preserving.*

Comment: Such a lovely explanation, thank you. Insight into the `getopt()` level of parsing is especially helpful. In my head scratchings I'd completely forgotten about the possibility of `-t0.05` (no space) and what that implies, too. Great stuff!

Comment: Yah, it boils down to `date` scanning integer arguments with ` %d` optional-leading-whitespace-then-a-decimal-integer  and `read` scanning them with `%d`, just decimal-integer, no leading whitespace accepted. `read -t ' 1'` gets rejected too.

Comment: @jthill, except that `scanf("%d")` accepts and discards leading whitespace. The POSIX description says _"Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a [, c, C, or n conversion specifier."_ Also, `%d` wouldn't do, since it can take a fractional number. Bash uses its own code for parsing that.

Answer (score 4):

```
read_flags="-t 0.05"
read "$read_flags" -srn 1
```

Here, `"$read_flags"` is in double quotes, so it's not [wordsplit](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). As you saw, the result is the same as running

```
read "-t 0.05" -srn 1
```

which means the specified timeout indeed has a leading space. Now, apparently whatever Bash does to parse the number doesn't like that.

What the extra space does, depends totally on the program. When parsing a number, it should be easy enough to ignore any leading white space, and the standard `strtod()` function does just that. With `date -d`, it has to parse a more complex string, so it's not surprising it's not strict about whitespace. (It could be something like `12:00 Jun  4 2019 UTC + 5 days` and not just a single number.) Hard to say why Bash is so picky here.

Now, if you were passing a filename, a string with a leading space would be a different filename than the one without, and it'd be hard for any program to know to ignore it.

---

With such simple values (without glob characters and where you want to split on *each* run of whitespace, assuming the default `IFS`), you could indeed use a string instead of an array, you just need to *not* quote it, so that it is split into two distinct arguments. So, `read $read_flags ...`. Or just set `timeoutflag=-t0.05` and then `read "$timeoutflag" ...`. Though note that `read "$timeoutflag"` isn't optimal in that if the variable is empty, it will get passed as a distinct empty argument, giving an error.

In general, arrays are the correct way to store and use arbitrary lists of arguments without issues.

Somewhat related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: Thank you, this was also very useful in helping me with more understanding and insight. It seems that this revolves around wordsplitting - or *not* (as @AdminBee stresses).