# write a line before it is executed without writing it twice

Tags: bash

I write a bash script with a `--verbose` option, where I want to write most lines before I execute them

```
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" $TOUCHPAD_DECELERATION
```

I would like to have exactly that output with quotes but the variables execuded, so the user can copy and paste that command to execute it again.

This would be the (more and more complicated, if there are a lot of quotes in the command) workaround with writing the line twice:

```
echo 'xinput --set-prop "'"$TP"'" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" '"$TOUCHPAD_DECELERATION"
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" $TOUCHPAD_DECELERATION
```

How can I write the outcome ot this line with echo without having to write twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `set -x` option. [`set -x` will](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

If you write:

```
set -x
var="Hello world"
echo "I say: " $var
```

then the output will be:

```
+ var='Hello world'
+ echo 'I say:' Hello world
I say: Hello world
```

The `+` is the value of `PS4`. To suppress it, add `PS4=` after your `set -x` line, or change it by setting `PS4` to another value.

`set -x` can also be enabled with `set -o xtrace`. To disable the option again, use `set +x`.

If there are only some commands you want to print out, you can run them in a subshell:

```
( set -x ; echo "I say: " $var )
+ echo 'I say:' Hello world
I say: Hello world
```

Putting the command in parentheses will apply `set -x` just for this command, and disable it automatically at the end.

Comment: That sounds nice, but How do you combine this with `if [ $VERBOSE ];` So it is only printed out, if --verbose is called?

Comment: @rubo77 just put the `set -x` within the `if` block: `if [ $VERBOSE ]; then set -x; fi` or, better, `$VERBOSE && set -x`.

Comment: ok, and then put a set +x after each of those lines

Comment: @rubo77 no. You only need to do it once, at the start of your script.

Comment: If I would put `set -x` at the top, then the whole script will be printed out while executed, which is far too much. Only some lines should be verbose, so stopping with `set +x` is great, only a drawback, that it also prints out this last command: `+ set +x`

Comment: The solution for me is: I put this before the first verbose command line: `( $VERBOSE && set -x` and in the line after the last command a closing bracket `)`

Answer (score 2):

I use a function for things like this:

```
#########################################################
# Function to facilitate printing of commands being run #
#########################################################
runthis(){
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    eval "$@"
}
```

Now, whenever I want to run a command in my script, I run it like this

```
runthis xinput --set-prop \"$TP\" \"Device Accel Constant Deceleration\" \"$TOUCHPAD_DECELERATION\"
```

Comment: It doesn't quote parameters, so "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" will become four separate arguments if you copy and paste it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer no it won't. Note that I am passing that string quoted and so, since `"$@"` is also quoted, it will be treated as a single argument. You can test this by adding `for i in "$@"; do echo "$i"; done` in the function. You might also want to read [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571).

Comment: It outputs (say) `xinput --set-prop hello Device Accel Constant Deceleration this is a test`. There are no quotes **in the output** to be copy-pasted (although `echo` does get them as single arguments because it's $@, yes).

Comment: @MichaelHomer ah, yes you're quite right. I had missed the part of the question that explained that the objective was to copy/paste the command. Bugger, that complicates things, I was forced to use `eval`.

Comment: Ah I see, you need to add backslashes in the call everywhere then, ok.

Comment: @rubo77 yes. Michael's answer avoids that if you're OK with the format.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - the `set -x` behavior of parameter quoting is hardly a guaranteed thing either. it is `bash`'s behavior, yes, but should be relied upon.

Comment: @mikeserv: It's explicitly a Bash question, twice over. You can rely on Bash having its own behaviour.