# How to put $@ in quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, quoting, parameter

My bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -r --color=always $@ . | nolong
```

The file is saved in `/usr/bin/findstr`

Everything's ok when I run this:

```
findstr hello
```

But when I run this:

```
findstr hello world
```

It searches only for hello.

**Question:** How can I put `$@` in quotes, so that it would understand it is a single parameter?

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to search for the regexp that is the concatenation of the arguments with space characters in between, that would be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
IFS=' ' # used for "$*"
grep -r --color=always -e "$*" . | nolong
```

`"$*"` joins the positional parameters with the first character (actually *byte* except with `yash`) of `$IFS`.

Note (as you seem to be confused by the meaning of space) that if you run:

```
myscript hello world
myscript hello  world
myscript 'hello'   "world"
```

The spaces (or quotes) are  not passed to `myscript`, they are just part of the shell command-line syntax. In those 3 shell command lines, `myscript` receives the same 3 arguments: "myscript", "hello" and "world".

If you want to search for any of the regexps passed as arguments:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for i do
  set -- "$@" -e "$i"
  shift
done
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && grep -r --color=always "$@" . | nolong
```

Comment: `myscript` receives the argument "myscript", are you sure about that?

Comment: @AaronFranke, the script will be invoked as with the `execve("/path/to/myscript", ["myscript", "hello", "world"], environ)` system call (`myscript` is `argv[0]` at that point). Which because of the she-bang will become `execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh" or "myscript", "/path/to/myscript", "hello", "world"])` and `sh` will make `$0` `/path/to/myscript`, and the original `myscript` `argv[0]` will be lost (to the script at least).

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the argument when your script is called to show that it is one argument and not two independent arguments. Inside your script you then have to use `"$@"`.

```
grep -r --color=always "$@" . | nolong
```

And the call is (for example)...

```
findstr "hello world"
```

(But note that the grep pattern uses just one argument, so `"$1"` instead of `"$@"` would have sufficed.)

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it to work without quotes when I use findstr? I.e. findstr hello world instead of findstr "hello world"

Comment: This is a case where you would want `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` -- you want to pass a *single argument* to grep.