# Function to simplify grep with an often used log

Tags: grep, pipe, cat, function

I'm trying make a function that simplifies grepping a log I have to work with on a regular basis.

I'd like to use extended regexp with it pipe and redirect the output, etc.

But I'm having trouble doing this using the standard *grep pattern file* syntax in the function.

The way I have it set up now is horrible to look at, but gets the job done:

```
alias mygrep='cat /path/to/logs/my.log | grep'
```

This allows me to run the following without trouble

```
mygrep -i -E "WARN|java" |less
```

Seems like the correct implementation should be something like the following.

```
function mygrep () {
    args=$*
    grep "$args" /path/to/logs/my.log
}
```

However when I use this with the search and pipe parameters above, grep returns  an *invalid option* error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try dropping the `$args` and just saying `grep "$@" /path/to/logs/my.log`.

Comment: You might also be interested in [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571)

Comment: Not a noobish question at all. This trips up even vets, and at least you did your homework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code has `$args` quoted:

```
grep "$args" /path/to/logs/my.log
```

This asks to pass the entire value of that variable as a single
parameter to grep. Thus, if you call `mygrep` with parameters `-i` and
`-E`, `grep` will in fact receive a single parameter `-i -E`, which is
indeed invalid.

The following should do it:

```
function mygrep () {
    grep "$@" /path/to/logs/my.log
}
```

Writing `"$@"` does the right thing: it's similar to `$*`, except that
it properly expands each parameter to a single word.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!  Also thanks to everyone who responded so cordially and helpfully.