# Bash alias with a space as a part of the command

Tags: bash, shell, alias, function, parameter

I'm trying to create a bash alias, where the alias itself has a space in it.

The idea is that the alias (i.e. `con`) stands for `sudo openvpn --config /path/to/my/openvpn/configs/`. Which results in a readable command, when the `con` alias is used.

i.e: `` `con uk.conf` == `sudo openvpn --config /path/to/my/openvpn/configs/uk.conf` ``

I understand that I can't declare the alias like this:
`con ="sudo openvpn --config /path/to/my/openvpn/configs/"`.
Would bash functions work in this scenario? I've never heard of that, but when researching a solution for this minor issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use a function. An alias would work if you wanted to add a parameter, any arguments given to aliases are passed as arguments to the aliased program but *as separate parameters*, not simply appended to what is there. To illustrate:

```
$ alias foo='echo bar'
$ foo
bar
$ foo baz
bar baz
```

As you can see, what was echoed was `bar baz` and not `barbaz`. Since you want to concatenate the value you pass to the existing parameter, you'll need something like:

```
function com(){ sudo openvpn --config /path/to/my/openvpn/configs/"$@"; }
```

Add the line above to your `~/.bashrc` and you're ready to go.

Comment: You can use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` so that subsequent arguments are passed through, too.  (General comment, possibly irrelevant to the specific case here)

Comment: @TobySpeight D'oh! I should have thought of that. Thanks, edited.

Comment: @TobySpeight just for clarification, does that mean `com uk.conf -something else` would translate to `sudo openvpn --config /path/to/my/openvpn/configs/uk.conf -something else`?

Comment: @TomHart yes. `$@` contains all parameters given. See [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571).