# How do I create a command prefix for bash with an alias?

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to create a bash alias that would act as a prefix, and could be parsed without needing to use a space. Basically, I have a set of commands that all start with the same first few characters, and I would like to prefix them with another command before running it without having to type that prefix out every time.

In other terms, I want to be able to create an alias that would work like this: `alias pref="sudo commandtoprefix"` would make it so that running `prefcommand` would run `sudo commandtoprefixcommand`. *Note the lack of space, it is important.*

I think I was able to do it at some point by simply doing as described, but for some reason it now doesn't work and returns a `command not found` error.

I've stumbled upon [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247119/bash-alias-with-a-space-as-a-part-of-the-command), but it is describing a function and therefore requires the use of a space, which doesn't exactly fit my needs.

Is there a way I could do this with aliases or functions that wouldn't require using a space?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a simple alias or function, but with bash, I think you could make a readline shortcut that replaces a string like`prf` with `sudo commandtoprefix` anywhere in the command line. *But* the replacement cannot be the originally string. So `pref` for `sudo commandtoprefix` is not possible, but you can use `prf`, for example: `bind '"prf": "sudo commandtoprefix"'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function which does something similar.

`function pref { prefix$*; }`

And subsequently call `pref command arg arg`, calling `prefixcommand arg arg`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on not using spaces, and also insist that the list of possible commands to prefix in this way not be determined in advance, the only way I can think of to accomplish this would be to use a custom "command not found" handler.

Bash calls the function `command_not_found_handle()` if you enter a non-existing command. You could exploit this to have the function check if the first four letters are `pref`, and if so, check if what follows is the name of an actual command, and if so, run it with sudo, and otherwise just report the usual error.

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    # read the "missing command" entered
    missingcmd="$1"
    # remove it from the argument list
    shift
    # check if starts with "pref"
    if [[ "${missingcmd:0:4}" == "pref" ]] ; then
        # read part after "pref"
        prefixedcmd="${missingcmd:4}"
        # check if it's a real command
        if which "$prefixedcmd" &> /dev/null ; then
            # run sudo with the cmd and the rest of the argument list
            sudo "$prefixedcmd" "$@"
            return $?
        fi
    fi
    # default command not found behavior
    echo "bash: $missingcmd: not found" >&2
    return 127
}
```

Put that in your `.bashrc`.

EDIT: I realize I may have misunderstood your question; it may be that there's a common prefix to the commands you want to do this with already, and you want to leave that out when using the special sudo-adding prefix. That should be possible too if you just change my line:

```
prefixedcmd="${missingcmd:4}"
```

To

```
prefixedcmd="commonprefix${missingcmd:4}"
```