# easy ssh connections with multiple servers

Tags: bash, ssh

my goal is to be able to type:

- srv01.sms and it connects to srv01.anything0.example
- srv02.mail and it connects to srv02.anything1.example

I know that i can edit my .ssh/config file to do something like this, but i don't want to edit my .ssh/config file for 500 servers

Is there a way to do this? In ssh config? bash aliases?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I create a command prefix for bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697465/108618) You want `ssh` where the other user wants `sudo`, but the rest seems similar.

Comment: I thought it was clear you want to type `srv01.sms`, but the answer that "really helped you" requires you to type `ssh srv01.sms`, so I'm confused. Your comment under the answer makes me believe that `srv01.smsandmore.example` is not really what you want, possibly `srv01.andmore.example` or something. Ideally the question like yours should state clear requirements and stick to them. You can [edit] (a good step after "sorry that I didn't wrote that"), but remember an edit that invalidates existing answer(s) is not a good thing. Please at least clarify if typing `ssh srv01.sms` is acceptable.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do with your ssh connections, you may want to look at using ansible in order to leverage dynamic inventories

Answer (score 4):

If you only have very few patterns (sms/mail), but a large number of servers, then you can use the patterns supported by ssh_config

> A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, ‘*’ (a wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or ‘?’ (a wildcard that matches exactly one character).

(from [ssh_config(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html#PATTERNS)).

along with the `%h` (the remote hostname) token in the Hostname specification:

```
Host srv*.sms
    Hostname %handmore.example


Host srv*.mail
    Hostname %handmore.example
```

Now any attempt to run `ssh srv<xyz>.sms` will connect to `srv<xyz>.smsandmore.example`, likewise for `.mail`.

Comment: Great answer this really helped me! Sorry that i didn't wrote that in my question but the %h takes the full line. Do you know how it only takes everything that is in front of the . ?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to only match the part before the . with SSH.