# Escape shell arg from one script to another

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

Given `./mysh0`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec ./mysh1 $*
```

And `./mysh1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

How do I call `mysh0` such that the arguments to `mysh1` and what's eventually printed are "A", "B 2" and "C"?

Calling this as `./mysh0 A "B 2" C` does not work.

Comment: Using `"$@"` instead of `$*`, note the quotes. See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/38906

Comment: Hmm. Anyway working around it? I'm afraid `./mysh0` is an intermediate script that I do not own.

Comment: No, you can not. You must control the `mysh0`, because it decided how to pass argument to `mysh1`.

Comment: Ok got it! Mind posting this as an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `"$@"` instead of `$*`:

```
exec ./mysh1 "$@"
```

That's the right way to expand all positional arguments as separated words.

When you use `$*`, all positional arguments was concatenated in to one long string, with the first value of `IFS` as separator, which default to a whitespace, you got `A B 2 C`.

Now, because you use `$*` without double quote (which [can lead to security implications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906) and [make your script choked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906)), the shell perform `split+glob` on it. The long string you got above was split into four words, `A`, `B`, `2` and `C`.

Therefore, you actually passed four arguments to `mysh1` instead of three.