# How can I wrap variable expansion in quotes?

Tags: bash, shell

My bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x 

./test FLAGS=${@:2}
```

And when I run `./script 1 2 3` the command that is executed is `./test FLAGS=2 3`. I want `FLAGS="2 3"`.

When I change the fourth line to `./test FLAGS="${@:2}"` there's no change.

When I change the fourth line to `./test FLAGS=\"{@:2}\"` I get `./test 'FLAGS="2' '3"'` which really isn't what I want.

How do I simply wrap my variables in quotes?

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem (asking about your concept of the solution rather than your original problem you're trying to solve with that solution).  Since you're using the variable name `FLAGS`, is it possible that what you're actually trying to do here is *parse options* in your script?

Comment: No, my script needs to execute another script using the parameters passed to it. Replace FLAGS with any other name, I chose it arbitrarily.

Comment: `test` is both a shell builtin and a standard utility (try `type -a test`): you should choose a different name for your program.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
"${*:2}"
```

instead of

```
"${@:2}"
```

`$@`, and `${x[@]}`, and their variants, [expand to one "word" per element in the array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters#index-_0040) when quoted. `$*` (and `${x[*]}`) [expand to a single word with all the elements joined together](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002a) using the first character of `$IFS`.

If they're not quoted at all, both versions undergo [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and create multiple words split wherever any of the characters of [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-IFS) occur.

Comment: When I do `FLAGS="${*:2}"`, it results in `'FLAGS="1 2"'` how do I get rid of the wrapping single quotes?

Comment: @derek, that's just how `set -x` outputs things. The actual `./test` program will receive a single argument but it won't have to deal with those single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, my understanding is that you want to discard (or store somewhere) the first argument, and then use the rest of the arguments as arguments to another script or command that you are calling from within your script.

If that's so, you can do it pretty easily, and you don't need to set a variable (`FLAGS` or anything else) to pass the script's parameters to the command within your script.  See the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

original_first_arg="$1"     # Use this line if you need to save the value to use later.

shift
mycommand "$@"
```

The `shift` command is a `bash` builtin.  By itself (without giving it any number), it just throws away the script's first argument (positional parameter).  From the manpage:

```
   shift [n]
          The  positional  parameters  from n+1 ... are renamed to $1 ....
          Parameters represented by the numbers  $#  down  to  $#-n+1  are
          unset.   n  must  be a non-negative number less than or equal to
          $#.  If n is 0, no parameters are changed.  If n is  not  given,
          it  is assumed to be 1.  If n is greater than $#, the positional
          parameters are not changed.  The return status is  greater  than
          zero if n is greater than $# or less than zero; otherwise 0.
```

Then `"$@"` expands to exact parameters you gave the script, minus the first one `$1` since that was thrown away by the `shift` command.

Further reading:

- [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/135943)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Comment: Please don't downvote without a comment.  I put work into this answer.

Comment: The addendum just isn't correct. The documentation is a bit screwy here, but you can try it: `bash -c 'set abc def ghi ; echo "${*:2}"'`.

Comment: You are correct, and the documentation is indeed screwy.  I've removed the incorrect addendum.  Mind reversing the vote?  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want different sets of parameters based on your script's args, then you *can* use functions for that:

```
other_script(){ shift; command other_script "$@"; }
other_script "$@"
```

It's how I typically do it. A function can call another function, or itself, or define a new function - or redefine itself. Every function gets an array.