# Perform parameter expansion before brace expansion?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

Bash manual says that brace expansion is performed before any other expansions.

I am writing a script which accepts two arguments:

```
#! /bin/bash

for b in {$1..$2}; do echo $b; done
```

I run it like:

```
$ ./myscript 0002 0010
{0002..0010}
```

The output isn't what I hope. 
I hope to perform parameter expansion before brace expansion. 
The expected output of my example is `0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 0010`, not `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. What would you  replace `{$1..$2}` with?

I hope that the solution works even when `$1` and `$2` are strings not just made of digits, but also made of letters and digits.

Note that the values `$1` and `$2` can only be given as arguments to the script. I think it is clear from the beginning, but point it out in case not.

Comment: `seq $1 $2`? `eval`?

Answer (score 2):

To do what you ask for: perform parameter expansion before brace expansion.

We need to delay brace expansion, that is easily done by quoting it `\{...\}` and calling eval:

```
$ set -- 5 10
$ eval printf \'%s \' \{$1..$2\}
5 6 7 8 9 10
```

That would work fine as long as there are no commands inside `$1` or `$2`.
That is a security risk of this solution. One way to mitigate the issue is to make sure that the variables only contain numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=${1//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from first parameter.
b=${2//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from second parameter.

c=$(eval printf \'%s \' \{$a..$b\})

for i in $c; do echo "$i"; done
```

The above code is missing some quoting that this version corrects:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${1//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from first parameter.
b=${2//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from second parameter.
c=( $(eval printf \'%s \' \{$a..$b\}) )

for i in "${c[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done

### Or just
# printf '%s\n' "${c[@]}"
```

But to print a list of numbers, an arithmetic `for` loop looks as a better solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=${1//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from first parameter.
b=${2//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from second parameter.

for (( i=$a; i<=$b; i++)); do
    printf '%0*d\n' 5 "$i"
done
```

Use it as:

```
$ script.sh 5 15
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
00010
00011
00012
00013
00014
00015
```

Answer (score 1):

[Brace Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Expansions) is not defined by POSIX, so perhaps you could ditch it
altogether:

```
seq $*
```

Or:

```
j=$1
while [ $j -le $2 ]
do
  echo $j
  j=$((j+1))
done
```

Or:

```
echo $* | awk '{for (j = $1; j <= $2; j++) print j}'
```

Comment: Thanks. What if `$1` and `$2` are not numbers, but strings made of letters and digits? What would you replace `{$1..$2}` with? For example the expected output of my example is `0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 0010`, not `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

Comment: printf on each value returned by seq

Comment: Also consider when `$1` and `$2` are made of letters.

Comment: @StevenPenny: You might want to get into the habit of using `"$@"` instead of `$*`.

Comment: @G-Man: why the habit?

Comment: Because of what happens when somebody runs *`scriptname `* `"foo bar"  "cat dog"` — see [What is the difference between $* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/80216)

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

seq -w $1 $2
```

This may be what you find!