# Error when eval a for-loop

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I am writing a script which accepts two arguments:

```
#! /bin/bash

eval  for i in {$1..$2}; do echo $i;  done
```

I run it like:

```
$ ./myscript 0002 0010
 syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Why is the error?

I though it might be because the looping should be grouped. But by replacing `eval  for i in {$1..$2}; do echo $i;  done` with `eval { for i in {$1..$2}; do echo $i;  done; }`, the error remains.

Note: 
I hope to perform parameter expansion before brace expansion by using `eval`. 
The desired output of my example is `0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 0010`. (See [Perform parameter expansion before brace expansion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278256/perform-parameter-expansion-before-brace-expansion))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the shell evaluated `;`, so `eval` didn't see it.

You have to escape any shell special character to delay its evaluation and pass is literally to `eval`:

```
eval for i in \{"$1".."$2"\}\; do echo \"\$i\"\;  done
```

Comment: This works; so +1.  However, I think the right answer is "don't do this": `seq` can accomplish the same thing without the security issues of `eval` which, in this case can be harmlessly demonstrated by running the script with two carefully chosen arguments like `./myscript.sh 02 '0010}; do echo "Whats for lunch?"; done; touch newfile; for i in {1..2'`

Comment: @John1024: That's right. But I guess the OP seems to have the knowledge about that problem, by observing his questions before, so, I mainly focus on the *why*. Please feel free to make any edit.

Comment: @John1024 `seq` isn't the right solution here either. The right thing is to use a numerical loop: `for ((i=$1; i<=$2; i++))` in bash or `i=$1; while [ "$i" -e "$2" ]` in sh.

Answer (score 2):

That line breaks at the first metacharacter, which is `;` (in this example).
The line:

```
eval for i in {$1..$2}; do echo $i;  done
```

Is divided into this three commands:

```
eval for i in {$1..$2};
do echo $i;
done
```

Trying to execute a `do` without having a previous `for`, `while`, `until` can not work. It will raise an error condition:

> syntax error near unexpected token `do'

That happens because the previous `for` is hidden as an argument in the command `eval`.

One possible workaround is to quote everything and leave out only what you want to be expanded, which I believe you want the variables `$1` and `$2`:

```
eval 'for i in {'$1'..'$2'}; do echo $i;  done'
```

It does work:

```
$ ./myscript 0002 0010
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
```

However, this script is `eval`uating external input, a highly insecure practice.

## Correct Solution

A safer script which sanitize $1 and $2 and properly quote the vars, is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${1//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from first parameter.
b=${2//[^0-9]/}          ### select only numbers from second parameter.
eval  'for i in {'"$a"'..'"$b"'}; do echo $i;  done'
```