# How to deal with insecurity of `eval` evaluating external input in a script?

Tags: bash, security, eval

[Binaryzebra said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278525/674)

> this script is evaluating external input, a highly insecure practice.

What are some ways to deal with or even replace `eval` evaluating external inputs in a script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Just make sure that the arguments passed to `eval` are not coming from external input or that if they are, you've sanitized them before hand.

As in, don't do:

```
n=0
....
n=$((n + 1))
eval "var$n=$1"
```

`$n` is under *your* control, the content of `$1` is not. If `$1` is `foo;reboot` for instance, eval will receive the `var3=foo;reboot` code to interpret and that  will run reboot.

Use:

```
eval "var$n=\$1"
```

Then, instead, `eval` will receive `var3=$1` which is fine.

```
eval "$1=\$2"
```

Would be wrong as well. You'd need to make sure the content of `$1` is only from a set of accepted values (sanitizing):

```
unset -v var1 foo bar
case $1 in
  (var1 | foo | bar) eval "$1=\$2";;
  (*) echo >&2 unexpected variable name; exit 1;;
esac
```

Note that `eval` is not the only command that evaluate arbitrary code, there are plenty others like `sh`, `perl`, `awk`, `sed`, even `read`, `export`, `typeset`, `printf`, `test` or `[` in some shells, you need to be equally careful with them when passing external input as their arguments.