# how differently do an empty string and a list with 0 elements behave?

Tags: bash

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94200/674

> If there are no positional parameters ($# is 0), then "$@" expands to **nothing** (not **an empty string**, but **a list with 0 elements**)

So how differently do an empty string and a list with 0 elements behave?

Does "a list with 0 elements" mean "an array with 0 elements"? I don't see bash has the concept of `list`.

Can "nothing" mean something which is not necessarily a "list" or array?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most shells do not have a concept of a list (for variables).
That is not a defined type of content (separate from string or number).

However, the parameters of a command are a list.

That is a very special kind of data type, one that only `"$*"` or `"$@"` would express as a list. But with differences:

```
$ set -- one two t33
$ printf '<%s> ' "$*" ; echo
<one two t33>

$ printf '<%s> ' "$@" ; echo
<one> <two> <t33>

$ for s; do printf '<%s>' "$s" ; done; echo
<one><two><t33>
```

Having explained that, what the quote means is that a list of parameters with 0 elements is equivalent to a list with no elements.

- In short: the list disappears (there are no elements to print):

  ```
  $ set -- 
  $ echo $#
  0

  $ printf '<%s>' "$@" ; echo
  <>

  $ for s in "$*"; do echo "<a>" ; done
  <a>

  $ for s in "$@"; do echo "<a>" ; done
  $
  ```

The last code prints "nothing", not even an "empty" (null) string.

So, about your question:

> Can "nothing" mean something which is not necessarily a "list" or array?

No, "nothing" **is** necessarily a (empty) "list".
However, a "null string" is something.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `$#` gives you number of parameters. 0 is also a number, which indicates no parameters were gives. `$@` however, expands to nothing, which means you can't evalute it. (e.g check if there were any parameters at all).
Try it yourself in a script, and see how it behaves.

When you want to check how many parameters were provided, for example your script counts that **3 required parameters** are provided - you would `$#`.

When you need to actually do something with the parameters, you would use `$@`.

See some examples from [TLDP internal variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)