# How do I print out the byte size of each file in my Bash script?

Tags: shell-script, files, size

My current code is like so:

#### scan.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    byte = $(stat -c%s "$line");
    echo "$line : $byte";
done< <(ls *.$1)
```

The output would be like this:

```
./scan.sh cpp
./scan.sh: line 4: byte: command not found
arraysum.cpp :
./scan.sh: line 4: byte: command not found
countLines.cpp :
./scan.sh: line 4: byte: command not found
createtext.cpp :
./scan.sh: line 4: byte: command not found
multiproc1.cpp :
./scan.sh: line 4: byte: command not found
myWc.cpp :
./scan.sh: line 4: byte: command not found
test.cpp :
```

Basically my code will take one syntax and will search the directory based on that syntax. The problem is I want it to print out "name of file" + "byte size of file", only I can't seem to get that working.

Comment: It should be `byte=$(....`  -- get rid of the spaces around the `=` sign.

Answer (score 7):

In the syntax of Bourne-like shells like `bash`, there must not be any space around the `=` sign in assignments.

```
byte=value
```

Here though, parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea.

You can just write it:

```
#! /bin/sh -
stat -c '%n: %s' -- *."$1"
```

If you do need a loop, just write it:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
for file in *.$1; do
  stat -c '%n: %s' -- $file
done
```

Or if you have to use `bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s failglob
for file in *."$1"; do
  stat -c '%n: %s' -- "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do this that should work with the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) and its descendants (including bash and ksh), if you don't care too much about the exact output format:

```
$ for file in *; do if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -r "$file" ]; then wc -c "$file"; fi; done
      23 HEAD
     111 config
      73 description
```

If you also don't care too much about errors and corner cases (in which case, good luck to you):

```
$ for file in *; do wc -c $file; done
```

Notes:

- If you're writing this with bash or ksh, you're probably better off using `((` `))` or `[[` `]]` instead of `[` `]`. ([source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testsandcomparisons.html))
  Also, below, consider using `$(wc -c <"$file")` instead of `` `wc -c <"$file"` ``). ([source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html))
- `-f` tests to see if what you're looking at is an ordinary file (not a directory, device, pipe, socket, tty, or generally some weird thing that can't be said to have a size in bytes). `-r` tests that the file is readable, i.e., that `wc` has a chance of succeeding; if you're looking at huge files or files that you can't read, use `stat` as per your original version and Stéphane's answer.
- The quotes (`"$file"`) are necessary if any of the files have spaces or tabs in them (e.g., a file named `my stuff.txt`).
- If you do care about the exact format, you should probably use some combination of `` `wc -c <"$file"` `` (which will not print the filename) and `echo` or `echo -n` (which will print whatever you'd like).
- If the files of interest are arguments to a script, in that script use `"$@"` ([explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and)).

I agree with @stéphane-chazelas that you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`; but if you do, you don't need [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443085/what-does-cmd-args-mean-in-the-shell). You can more simply read the output of the command:

`ls | while IFS= read -r` *blah blah blah*

or, if you want to recurse through a directory:

`find` *blah* `-type f -print | while IFS= read -r` *blah blah*

or better still:

`find` *blah* `-type f print0 | xargs -o` *blah blah*

where `-print0` and `xargs -0` again properly handle filenames with spaces or tabs

Comment: The problem with using `wc` here is that it will read the whole contents of the file, which can quickly get pretty expensive on large files... Using `stat` is the correct approach here.

Comment: "pretty expensive on large files": I agree (and said so). But, what's a large file? To me, it's hundreds of megabytes. For anything smaller, performance optimization is unnecessary. Since @li-wang appears to be counting bytes in .cpp files, I think `wc` is appropriate.