# Handle filenames containing whitespaces passed to Bash function using wildcard

Tags: bash, shell-script

How is it possible to make a Bash function handle properly filenames containing a whitespace when filenames are passed using wildcard?

```
$ touch a "a b" b
$ ls -1 *
a
a b
b

$ function foo { ls -1 $*; }
$ foo *
a
a
b
c
```

I'd like to define a function foo that returns the same results as `ls -1 *` does when executed as `foo *`. I tried `$@` instead of `$*` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and) - note in particular the discussion of quoting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your function is supposed to do, taking into consideration how it's called. But here's a possible solution.

```
foo () { ls -1 "$@"; }
```

This function is supposed to call `ls -1` with the function's positional arguments passed to the command. How does it work?

```
$ touch a "a b" b
$ ls -1 .
a
a b
b
$ foo .
a
a b
b
```

And this one also works:

```
$ foo *
a
a b
b
```

But you need to know the difference between `foo .` and `foo *`. The former passes `.` as the argument to the function `foo`, and then it internally passes the same to `ls -1`. With `foo *` the situation is different as `*` is expanded to a list of arguments to the function `foo`, and then the arguments need to be handled internally. That's accomplished in my function with `"$@"`, which expands the positional arguments taking care of whitespace. If you omit the quoting around `$@`, you end up with this:

```
$ goo () { ls -1 $@; }
$ goo .
a
a b
b
$ goo *
a
a
b
b
```

Finally, you can analyse the difference between `"$*"` and "$@".

```
$ hoo () { ls -1 "$*"; }
$ hoo .
a
a b
b
$ hoo *
ls: cannot access 'a a b b': No such file or directory
```

"$*" is not the right one here, definitely.

```
$ foo . .
.:
a
a b
b

.:
a
a b
b
$ hoo . .
ls: cannot access '. .': No such file or directory
```