# Bash: Sourcing file with an Array into main script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I have a script, which will parse an array like:

```
#!/bin/bash
URLs=(
...
"https://www.example.com"
"https://www.example.com/contact"
);
for URL in ${URLs[*]} ; ...
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to outsource the `URLs` array into another file, pass that file as `$1` and source it (`source $1`) into my script. Unfortunately `URLs` stays empty.

This is the file with the outsourced URLs array, which I'm trying to pass:

```
#!/bin/bash
URLs=(
...
"https://www.example.com"
"https://www.example.com/contact"
);
```

I'm calling the script like this:

```
./original.sh /absolute/path/to/array.sh
```

And, of course the `original.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $1;
for URL in ${URLs[*]} ; ...
# e.g. curl ${URL}
# Tried also:
for URL in ${URLs[@]} ; ...
```

The idea is that I have different lists/files with URLs, which need to be passed to one single script in order to be parsed. Does anyone has an idea how I could do that?

Comment: Works fine for me. Please edit your question and add your full (minimal) working script. Generally, you should use `"${URLs[@]}"`. [See this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Comment: You did that from an external file, where `URLs` is kept? If you trigger it in the same file, it works for me, too.

Comment: yes, from an external file.

Comment: What does your file look like that you're trying to source?

Comment: @Kusalananda: It starts with `#!/bin/bash` and is followed by the array declaration `URLs=( ... );`.

Comment: and the second script?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks for you notice, I fixed that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: your script "original.sh" is still not included...

Comment: @RoVo: Yes sorry for that, fixed that.

Comment: I think you did not add your exact script, because what you posted works fine. But maybe you have some issue as you're missing some quoting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any issue in your script, it works for me, although you should always use quoted `"${var[@]}"` notation and also use quotes around variables / file names (`source "$1"`).

---

This works well:

script `array.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
URLs=(
"example"
"something"
"something else"
)
```

script `original.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "$1"
for URL in "${URLs[@]}"; do
    echo "$URL"
done
```

works well for me:

```
$ ./original.sh array.sh
example
something
something else
```

---

Easier solution of loading list data without needing to source using `readarray`:

config:

```
example
something
something else
```

script:

```
readarray URLs < config
for URL in "${URLs[@]}"; do
    echo "$URL"
done
```

or using `xargs`:

```
 xargs -a config -I{} echo {}
```

or feed it directly into `wget` or `aria2c` if your goal is to download the urls:

```
wget -i config
aria2c -i config
```

Comment: Yes, of course it works, I had a very strupid mistake I overlooked, sorry for that and thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Nevermind, mistakes happen to everyone. And the most stupid mistakes are the most difficult to see. Would you tell us what the mistake was?

Comment: If I tell you, you will kill me :) I forgot to remove an `exit`, which I have placed at the beginning where I performed some tests in order not to trigger the remaining execution of the script. I recognized it as I triggered the script with `/bin/bash -x` - I'm very sorry! Sh** happens )))))