# A .bashrc function to save quick notes/ interesting commands

Tags: bash, shell-script

Often, I want to note down something really quicky when working in the terminal - Something to do, something interesting, etc. So I thought I'd include this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
export QUICKY="$HOME/Documents/Notes/quickies"
quicky(){
  if (( $# == 0 )) ; then
    vim $QUICKY
    return
  fi
  for i in $@; do
    echo "$i" >> $QUICKY
  done
}
```

So this is really simple. A use case would be something like `quicky meeting` to quicky note about a meeting or something similar. I would just do `quicky` to read the notes and further organize if I wanted.

Suppose I do something like `quicky "Feed the dog"`, I expect a new line `feed the dog` in $QUICKY, but every word appears in a new line. How can I tackle this issue?

PS. quicky "!!" would be excellent to quicky note down interesting commands that you want to read about later.

Although suggestions and answers about any other ready-made tools are alright, I would like to know how I'd do this with bash.

Comment: `echo "$@" >> $QUICKY` will do; no need to loop.

Comment: @sitaram I need them separated by newlines

Comment: huh!  My English must be different from yours.  To me, "but every word appears in a new line" means you did *not* want that.  I'll just walk away from this; no need to reply

Comment: @sitaram Alright walk away... What I meant was `quicky "feed the dog" "go to meeting"` should have the two args on two different lines. Is that too difficult to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#131767). Try this:

```
quickFile="$HOME/Documents/Notes/quickies"
quicky(){
  if (( $# == 0 )) ; then
    vim "$quickFile"
    return
  fi
  for i in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i" >> "$quickFile"
  done
}
```

I changed your variable name so it isn't CAPITALIZED. It's generally better to avoid al caps variable names in shell scripts to avoid name clashes with environment variables. I also used `printf` since [that is a better option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#65819) for printing arbitrary data.

Comment: A quick diversion... What happens if I use `for i in $*` instead of `for i in $@` ? I mean, what is the technical distinction - they both seem similar to me...

Comment: @SuraajKS see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571.

Comment: huh?  Wouldn't the `\n` in the printf cause the same problem OP asked to fix (i.e., each word appearing on its own line)?

Comment: @sitaram no, because here the `$@` is correctly quoted as `"$@"`. It is the quoting that fixes the issue, not the use of `printf`.

Comment: Maybe I could also do `(IFS=$'\n' ; echo "$*" >> $quickFile' ; )` ... (Although I have no idea why `IFS="\n"` just doesn't work)