# Bash Operators for scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

I have two scripts that work together by themselves and I have no idea how to make them work together

the task is to
make a bash script accept operators and a list of integers and having the command perform the operations.

I basically need to be able to use the script as such

```
test.sh add 1 2 3
5
test.sh sub 4 2 1
1
```

the first script I have is

```
for var in $@
do

sum=$(( sum + var ))
done
echo $sum
```

second script is

```
if [ $operator = add ]; then
add= echo $(($a+$b))

elif
```

Comment: (1) Never say `for var in $@`.  Either shorten it to `for var` or change it to ``for var in "$@"`` (note the quotes).  (2) What are you asking?  You say you want to do `test.sh add 1 2 3`, but then you say you want to do `test.sh 1 2 3`.  (3) Your second script is nearly what you want.  Your first script adds all the arguments; what part of that do you want?

Comment: Ah my mistake, I meant to put ```test.sh add 1 2 3 ``` for both

the first script allows it to do``` test.sh 1 2 3 ``` and I need it to be able to add numbers together to get an output so my example was ```test.sh add 1 2 3``` to get 5

Comment: ``` if [ $operator = add ]; then
        add= echo $(( sum + var ))
fi
echo $add ```

pops up an error

line 7: [: =: unary operator expected
 I'm not sure what is means

Comment: `$operator` is unset in your 2nd script, so the command sees `[ = add ]` and complains, that the first operand is missing.

Comment: What is your initial task? Why do you want to do this? Do you want to learn scripting (good, we can help, but probably there are easier ways to achieve it) or do you want to sum up numbers (you don't need to script it yourself,  rather use programs doing it for you).

Comment: see also: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm trying to get a grasp on how to get scripting down, and I'm struggling 

the task is just to write a bash script that accepts operators and a list of integers

Comment: Btw: why should `test.sh add 1 2 3` return `5` and not `6`?

Comment: I would do `calculator() { op=$1; shift; printf '%s\0' "$@" | paste -szd"$op" | xargs -0 echo 'scale=5;' | bc  ; }` and then run `calculator + 1 2 3` --> `6`  or `calculator '/' 1 2 3` --> `0.16666`

Comment: I'm just saying it is difficult to help you if we don't exactly know what you want to achieve,  especially because your second script's purpose and how it **should** work is unclear.

Comment: ``` test.sh add 1 2 3``` returns 5 because its adding the numbers together not multiplying them. what would I make operator equal? I need it to be able to do addition and subtraction.

my task is as follows

 using a loop command write a bash script that will accept an operator and a list of integers and have it execute the operation on the list

Comment: you know that  1+2+3 is 6 ?

Comment: wow I really am dyslexic, I've been working on this for a couple of hours, my bad

Answer (score 1):

A script that picks out its first command line argument into a separate variable called `op` and then removes this from the list of command line arguments:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

op=$1
shift
```

If this script is called with `add 1 2 3` as arguments, then the code would assign the string `add` to `op` and would leave `1 2 3` as the only three command line arguments in `"$@"`.

We may then loop over the remaining command line arguments:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

op=$1
shift

for arg do
    # some commands should go here
done
```

The added loop will make sure that the variable `arg` will take the value of each of the remaining command line arguments in turn.  We could also have written the start of the loop like `for arg in "$@"; do ...` but it's more to type and programmers sometimes forget to add the quotes around `$@`.

Depending on the value `$op` one of several operations may happen in the loop.  We may use a simple test to see what `$op` is and carry out the correct operation.  In any case, some value is being accumulated in `acc` below, and this `acc` value should (according to the way the commands are presented in the question) be initialized to the first number, and that number needs to be shifted off the list of arguments too.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

op=$1
shift

acc=$1
shift

for arg do
    case $op in
        add) acc=$(( acc + arg )) ;;
        sub) acc=$(( acc - arg )) ;;
        mul) acc=$(( acc * arg )) ;;
        div) acc=$(( acc / arg )) ;; # note: integer division here
        *)
            printf 'Unknown operation: %s\n' "$op" >&2
            exit 1
    esac
done

printf '%s\n' "$acc"
```

Testing this script after saving it and making it executable:

```
$ ./script add 1 2 3
6
$ ./script sub 4 2 1
1
$ ./script xor a b c
Unknown operation: xor
$ ./script add
script[7]: shift: nothing to shift
```

Note the two last invocations.  The last one failed to provide any numbers, so the second `shift` fails.  The second to last invocation notices that the operation is unknown and terminates prematurely.

By changing the assignment to `op` and the initialization of `acc` slightly, we can make the error messages slightly more useful:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

op=${1:?Expected operator}
shift

acc=${1:?Expected number}
shift

for arg do
    case $op in
        add) acc=$(( acc + arg )) ;;
        sub) acc=$(( acc - arg )) ;;
        mul) acc=$(( acc * arg )) ;;
        div) acc=$(( acc / arg )) ;; # note: integer division here
        *)
            printf 'Unknown operation: %s\n' "$op" >&2
            exit 1
    esac
done

printf '%s\n' "$acc"
```

Testing again:

```
$ ./script
script[3]: 1: Expected operator
$ ./script add
script[6]: 1: Expected number
$ ./script add 1 2
3
```

The exact formatting of these error messages may differ depending on what shell acts as `/bin/sh` on your system.

Comment: Might be worth noting that if `/bin/sh` happens to be based on `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh` (as opposed to ash-based shells, bosh, or yash) then [that script has an arbitrary code injection vulnerability](/q/172103). You'll also get  variations in behaviour if operands are floating point. A proper programming language (even `awk`) would be better suited than a shell here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! I'll insert a basic "check that string is an integer" test later today.

Answer (score 0):

Your first script is looping through `$@`, if you want to add an operand, you can save the first argument (`op=$1`) and then use `shift`.

from `man bash`:

> **shift [n]**
> The  positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed to $1 ....  Parameters represented by the numbers $# down to $#-n+1 are unset.  n must be a non-negative number less than or equal to $#.  If n is  0, no parameters are changed.  If n is not given, it is assumed to be 1.  If n is greater than $#, the positional parameters are not changed.  The return status is greater than  zero  if  n  is greater than $# or less than zero; otherwise 0.

Initialize `$result` with the first argument, then use `shift` again.

Also, make sure to quote `$@` when running the loop ([read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and) here).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
op=$1
shift
result=$1
shift
for var in "$@"; do
  result=$(( result $op var ))
done
echo "$result"
```

You could also do the `shift` in one step:

```bsh
op=$1
result=$2
shift 2
```

Run `test.sh + 1 2 3` or  `test.sh '*' 1 2 3` ...

(`'*'` must be quoted, to not expand to filenames).

---

However, I would rather use `bc` and `$IFS` instead of a loop and `$(( ... )))` for this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$1
shift
bc <<< "scale=5; $*"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

[See also:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41595/236063)

> `"$*"` expands to a single word `"$1c$2c..."`. Usually `c` is a space, but it's actually the first character of `IFS`, so it can be anything you choose.