# Understanding $@ in bash or zsh

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

`myFun1` and `myFun2` below don't produce the same output. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

myFun1() {
  local item
  IFS=:
  for item in "${@}"; do
    echo "->${item}<-"
  done
}

myFun2() {
  local items="${@}";
  local item
  IFS=:
  for item in "${items}"; do
    echo "->${item}<-"
  done
}
```

Invoking

```
myFun1 "a=b" "c='d 1'" "e"
```

produces

```
->a=b<-
->c='d 1'<-
->e<-
```

whereas

```
myFun2 "a=b" "c='d 1'" "e"
```

produces

```
->a=b c='d 1' e<-
```

Comment: Related - [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/100397)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is [defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02), which both Bash and Zsh make an effort to adhere to.

> `@`
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double-quotes, and where field splitting (see Field Splitting) is performed, each positional parameter shall expand as a separate field, ...

However, this behavior only applies to `$@` itself. Assigning its value to another variable causes the meaning of the individual fields to be lost, and it's then treated as a single string (just as if you used `$*`).

I'm not certain about Zsh, but if in Bash you want to save `$@` to another variable and be able to take advantage of field separation, you need to use an array.

```
myFun2() {
  local -a items=("${@}");
  local item
  IFS=:
  for item in "${items[@]}"; do
    echo "->${item}<-"
  done
}
```

In Bash, array expansion of the form `"${array[@]}"` has the same behavior as `"$@"`.

Comment: Also please keep in mind that shell arrays are not part of POSIX.