# bash use rest of the arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a bash script that takes a name and a command as arguments. Its pretty simple like this,

```
#myscript
echo $1
$2
```

And I run this like this

```
bash myscripts myjob ls
```

and it will echo the 'myjob' and run the `ls` command. But when the command is multi-word, I have to provide it with an inverted commas, like this

```
bash myscripts myjob "ls -l"
```

Now my question is, is there a way to write the shell script so that, I don't have to provide the inverted commas? Like, take everything as my command instead of the first argument? Is it possible to do with bash?

Comment: This is related to [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373), except that here, the arguments to the shell (`"$@"`) already contain the command to run as separate words so where to put them is not the problem. But you can modify and use the list as in that other question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you may use `shift` to shift previous arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
shift 1
"$@"
```

`shift N` will shift the counter so that arguments 1 to N are skipped and argument N+1 is now 1, N+2 is 2, and so on.

Note that this implies that your first command (`myjob`) is a single-word one and only the second command (`ls -l`) may be multiple-word.

Comment: That `$*` should be `"$@"` - otherwise if any of the args is a quoted string containing IFS characters, bash will word split it.  e.g. if the 2nd and subsequent are are `cp "filename with spaces.txt" "newfile.txt"`, it will become `cp filename with spaces.txt newfile.txt` (i.e. there will be **four** filename args, not two...three source filenames and one target: `filename`, `with`, `spaces.txt`, and `newfile.txt`).  and there'll be even worse problems if any of the args contain shell meta-characters like `;` or `&`.

Comment: @cas Correct and corrected. TY. [Detailed reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571)

Comment: @cas, syntax characters like `;&()` shouldn't be an issue when expanding `$*`, even if it's unquoted. Just `IFS` characters and glob characters. `set -- 'foo;' bar; echo $*` works ok and prints `foo; bar`, but `set -- foo "*" bar; echo $*` expands the `*` as a glob. But yes, it should be `"$@"` here, and even when one needs `$*`, it should probably be `"$*"` too.

Comment: true, i was thinking of `eval`.