# Assigning $* in shell script from args array

Tags: shell, scripting, variable, parameter, assignment

After iterating thru the shell arguments and filtering out unwanted arguments into an array, I want to assign the array back to `$*`.

For example, in the below script, I want to remove the arguments `-f java`, which are in sequence, and store the rest of the arguments in the `args` array.  Is there a way to assign the filtered arguments back to `$*`?

I am trying to do `set --${*} $args`, but it is taking only the first argument and not the whole array.

If I pass

```bash
$ .test.sh arg1 arg2 -f java7 arg3 
arg1 arg2 agr3
```

```bash
while (( $# )); do
    if [[ $1 = "-f" ]] && [[ $2 = "java7" ]]; then
        unset USE_JAVA8
        JAR=signals.jar
        echo "USE_JAVA8 Flag is OFF running Signal on java7"
        shift 2
        continue
    fi

    args+=( "$1" )
    shift
done


set --${*} $args

echo $*
```

Comment: In bash, `$arrayname` only gets the first element of the array; you want `"${arrayname[@]}"` (or in this case, `set -- "${args[@]}"`). You should almost never use `$*` or leave off the quotes, because either way it causes confusion between gaps between arguments and whitespace *within* arguments. See my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine/3816747#3816747) (about `$@`, not an array, but it works the same).

Comment: See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `bash` shell, `$args` would be the equivalent of `${args[0]}`, i.e., the first element of the array `args`.

To set the list of positional parameters to the values of the array `args`, you would use

```bash
set -- "${args[@]}"
```

Note that `"${args[@]}"` must be quoted exactly like this, or the individual elements of the array would potentially be split into multiple words by the shell and undergo filename globbing.  If you use `"$*"` (a single quoted string) or `"$@"` (a list of individually quoted strings), these should be used quoted for the same reason.

Also related:

- [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

---

In the `zsh` shell, `set -- $args` would correctly have set the list of positional parameters to the list of elements from the `args` array.