# How can I pass $@ to exec.args of Maven?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

things I tried in my script `run.sh`:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.App -Dexec.args="$@"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.App -Dexec.args=$@
```

when I call the script like:

```
./run.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

the arguments are not passed to Java application. instead Maven tries to interpret them as if they were maven options.

EDIT: I used `-x` option. I see this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.App -Dexec.args=arg1 arg2 arg3
```

How can I get it to evaluate to:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.App -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

that will fix my problem. I tried many variations, can't get it to work.

Comment: What is the output of debug using `YourShell -x`?

Comment: If none of the arguments can contain spaces or other funny characters, this might be one of the very few places you want `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` (i.e. `-Dexec.args="$*"` -- see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348443/a-confusion-about-array-versus-array-in-the-context-of-a-bash-comple/3355375#3355375)). If the arguments might need quoting or something similar it's more compicated. bash has a way to quote things in a bash-compatible way, but this probably requires different quoting/escaping syntax (and I don't know what that syntax is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the shell expands `-Dexec.args="$@"` and the list of positional parameters is `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`, then you get the list `-Dexec.args=arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` (three separate arguments for `mvn`). The `"$@"` expansion is always a list, and the result of concatenating that with a string, as you do in your code, is not actually well defined (most shells behave as I describe here).

What you *likely* want is `"$*"` in place of `"$@"`.  The expansion of `"$*"` is always a single string made up of the elements of the list of positional parameters, concatenated with the first character from `$IFS` (usually a space) as the delimiter.
With `-Dexec.args="$*"` you get the string `-Dexec.args=arg1 arg2 arg3` (one single argument for `mvn`).

So:

```bash
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.App -Dexec.args="$*"
```

Note that if any argument contains spaces, it will be difficult for `mvn` to parse it correctly unless the tool supports some special escaping, quoting, or other encoding for handling that (and you use that in the argument list).  I'm not a Maven user, so I don't know how it parses the `exec.args` value.

See also [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and)