# How can I find out how many lines a text file contains without viewing it?

Tags: text-processing, files, text

How can I find how many lines a text file contains without opening the file in an editor or a viewer application? Is there a handy Unix console command to see the number?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Indeed there is.  It is called `wc`, originally for word count, I believe, but it can do lines, words, characters, bytes (and with some implementations, the length in bytes of the longest line or the display width of the widest one).  The `-l` option tells it to count lines (in effect, it counts the newline characters, so only properly delimited lines):

```
wc -l mytextfile
```

Or to only output the number of lines:

```
wc -l < mytextfile
```

(beware that some implementations insert blanks before that number).

Comment: Yes `wc` is very useful, but it is worth noting that the *longest line length* option `-L` is quirky... see [wc -L reports a line-length of 8 for a tab-char](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20551/wc-l-reports-a-line-length-of-8-for-a-tab-char-bug-or-feature)

Comment: when I use this command, the system not only gives my number of lines, but also the 'name of the file' right next to the 'number of lines'. I am using bash shell on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Comment: @Abhinav Yes, it does that. If you need just the number, pipe it through `awk`: `wc -l mytextfile | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: Wow, this would actually be a legitimate use of cat: `cat mytextfile | wc -l`.

Comment: @Kevin piping the output of `wc` through `awk` makes no sense. In the case of only wanting the number, this can be accomplished in pure `awk` with no difficulty (see my answer).

Comment: @terdon Still a UUOC :).  `wc -l < mytextfile` will do the job.

Answer (score 11):

Another option would be to use `grep` to find the number of times a pattern is matched:

```
grep --regexp="$" --count /path/to/myfile.txt
```

In this example,

- `$` is an expression that evaluates to a new line (enter button is pressed)
- `--count` suppresses normal output of matches, and displays the number of times it was matched.
- The `/path/to/myfile.txt` is pretty obvious, I hope :)

**EDIT:** As mentioned by @hesse in the comments, this can be shortened to

```
grep -c $ path/to/file
```

Which would also make it standard and portable to non-GNU `grep` implementations.

Comment: Indeed another option... a terribly over-engineered option, granted, but an option.

Comment: This could also be written shorter: `grep -c $ some_file`

Comment: @ MichaelKjörling Dunno about 'terribly' over-engineered. If I was using this in a script or similar I would definitely want to use the lighter-weight wc. If I'm at a prompt and I'm curious about a file, I'd probably use grep, because I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: In my tests (on a GNU system), I find that `grep -c '^'` is significantly faster than `grep -c '$'`.

Answer (score 4):

I would also add that it is quite easy to do this in pure `awk` if you, for some reason, wished to not use `wc`.

```
$ awk 'END { print NR }' /path/to/file
```

The above `print`s the number of records (`NR`) present in the file at `/path/to/file`.

*Note*: unlike `wc`, this will not print the name of the file. So, if you only wanted the number, this would be a good alternative to `cat file | wc -l`.

Comment: This is good because if there's an unterminated line at the end, i.e. there's no newline character after it, `wc` will undercount. And it's not as overengineered as the `grep` option.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kevin suggested, you can use `wc` command to count lines in a file. However, `wc -l test.txt` will include the file name in the result. You can use:

```
wc -l < test.txt
```

to just get the number of lines without file name in it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, I can verify that the AWK is way faster than the other tools (GREP, SED, AWK, PERL, WC)

Here is the result of the test that I ran here

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S; grep -c $ my_file.txt; date +%x_%H:%M:%S;
```

*10/03/16_09:41:51 24579427 10/03/16_09:42:40 ~49 Seconds*

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S; wc -l my_file.txt; date +%x_%H:%M:%S;
```

*10/03/16_09:35:05 24579427 my_file.txt 10/03/16_09:35:45 ~40 Seconds*

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S; sed -n '$=' my_file.txt; date +%x_%H:%M:%S;
```

*10/03/16_09:33:50 24579427 10/03/16_09:34:29 ~39 Seconds*

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S; perl -ne 'END { $_=$.;if(!/^[0-9]+$/){$_=0;};print "$_" }' my_file.txt; date +%x_%H:%M:%S;
```

*10/03/16_09:36:11 24579427 10/03/16_09:36:36 ~25 Seconds*

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S; awk 'END { print NR }' my_file.txt; date
+%x_%H:%M:%S;
```

*10/03/16_09:43:36 24579427 10/03/16_09:43:58 ~22 Seconds*

Comment: You may want to specify your system and describe your modus operandi (size and shape of your file, is the file loaded in cache, on how many invocations did you take an average...). In all my tests, `wc` always comes out significantly faster than anything else as you'd expect from a specialised application.